# MSBuild via command line with multiple ReferencePath

Tags: msbuild

How do I pass multiple ReferencePath in MSBuild in the command line.  I'm currently using this

```
MSBuild /t:Rebuild "Solution1.sln" /p:ReferencePath="C:\My Library 1\obj\Debug; C:\My Library 2\obj\Debug"
```

MSBuild is returning an **MSB1006** error.  Take note that my reference paths have **spaces** in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what I do, I can't seem to make it work using MSBuild.  I now use [DEVENVE.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to compile my solution; it would read my user project settings where the ReferencePath is saved and use that to locate the correct version of the DLL I want to use.

Comment: If you are going to use visual studio to compile your code then you should call DEVENV.com and not DEVENV.exe. The exe will open up an instance of VS.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Try escaping the semicolons as %3b</s>

Try moving the quotes around the entire property expression, not just the values

```
/p:"Name=Value One;Value Two"
```

Comment: Didn't work.  It ignored ALL of the ReferencePath and used the reference path declared in the solution.

Comment: I still cannot, for the love of all things unholy, make it work!

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This worked for me:

msbuild {{slnPath}} /t:rebuild /p:OutDir={{outputpath}} /p:Configuration=Release

Specify /p for every parameter

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't working in powershell

```
msbuild C:\temp\project.sln /p:referencepath="C:\Checkout\References
\CRM 2011;C:\Checkout\References\Log4Net\4.0\release"
```

but works fine from an old fashioned cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

replacing the ';' with '3%B' seems to work in my setup with Nant and Jenkins